# How to materialize an RDD explicitly in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I need to read a large dataset from a file, convert it into a Spark matrix and run some machine learning algorithms on the matrix. I want to benchmark the speed of the machine learning algorithms. Because the Spark RDDs are always lazily evaluated, it's difficult to benchmark the machine learning algorithm. When I measure the runtime, it also includes the runtime for parsing the input file.

Is there a way to force Spark to materialize some RDDs? so that I can parse the input file in advance before running the machine learning algorithm?

Thanks,
Da

Comment: How about converting to dataframe and saveAsTable??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do something like this:

```
val persisted = rdd.persist(...);
```

Here it depends on size of your rdd, if it fits into memory provide memory only, otherwise - memory and disk level.

And then:

```
persisted.count();
// now you can use 'persisted', it's materialized
```

and then all other pipeline transformations (ml in your case)

so count is an action - so it materializes rdd and since you've persisted it before - next stages will take rdd from persisted storage and not from file

Comment: If you are persisting in memory only you can use val persisted = rdd.cache(). It has exactly the same effect as persist in memory only

Comment: I guess this is what you mean. I set the RDD persistent with data stored in memory and run count(). It does trigger Spark to parse the input file. However, when I run corr() on the persistent data, I don't see any speedup. Am I doing the right thing?

lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])

data = lines.map(parseVector)

data1 = data.persist(storageLevel=StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

data1.count()

start_time = time.time()

corr = Statistics.corr(data1, method=corrType)

end_time = time.time()

print("%s seconds" % (end_time - start_time))

Comment: Have you validated that your file can be stored in memory? It might be that bottleneck is in ml and not in parsing.

Comment: I guess I need to increase the heap size for JVM (now the heap size is much larger than the dataset size). After I did that, I do see some performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Shared Variables and Accumulators if your application (ML) is having multiple tasks that use data1.count (referring the comments section of @Igor)
refer to this [source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#shared-variables)