# Spark force a distributed join

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have a spark sql job where i am doing

```
Dataset<Row> currentDataSet = hdfsHandler.loadDataSet(sparkSession, "somelocation");
currentDataSet.createOrReplaceTempView(CURRENT_USER_VIEW);

Dataset<Row> previousDataSet = hdfsHandler.loadDataSet(sparkSession, "somelocation2);
previousDataSet.createOrReplaceTempView(PREVIOUS_USER_VIEW);

String currentRunColumn = "c.".concat("userid");
String previousRunColumn = "p.".concat("userid");

Dataset<Row> addedRecordDataSets = sparkSession.sql("SELECT " + currentRunColumn + " FROM " +
        CURRENT_USER_VIEW + " AS c " +
        " LEFT JOIN " + PREVIOUS_USER_VIEW + " AS p " +
        " ON " + currentRunColumn + " == " + previousRunColumn +
        " WHERE " + previousRunColumn + " IS NULL ");

dataSet.coalesce(1).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY()).foreachPartition(persist());
```

for this job 3 jobs are created

1. read from hdfs currentDataSet
2. read from hdfs previousDataSet
3. join two dataset, coalesce, call persist().

the 3rd step is executed only on 1 executor because foreachPartition(persist()) is the only terminal operation. If the datasets are huge it will take lots of time. is there a way i can do a distributed join and then only coalesce it?

one way i can think of is by adding one more terminal operator like count after computing addedRecordDataSets, but just that will not solve the issue i will have to cache as well so that we are not having to rejoin  the data. But caching is a costly operation. Is it possible to to just force materialise the dataset?

this questions seems to be relevant to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106593/how-to-materialize-an-rdd-explicitly-in-spark) SO

Comment: Just curious, what is a `persist()` in `....foreachPartition(persist())`?

Comment: It just does write to hdfs. For some reason, we have to write in a single file.

Comment: Would `persist(dataSet.cache().toLocalIterator())` serve the need better then? https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#toLocalIterator--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create what is called a stage barrier, something that will force spark not to push the coalesce and the join into the same stage.

If you can manage holding the whole result on a single partition, the join result probably isn't too large. Consider replacing `coalesce` with `repartition`, which will do a full shuffle but also create a stage barrier and perform the join in parallel. This was fast enough for my use cases but might not be best practice as `repartition` is an expensive operation.

It might be faster to call `df.localCheckpoint` which writes intermediate results to disk (but unlike `cache` creates a stage barrier) then `coalesce` but I haven't personally tried it.

More elaboration [here](https://youtu.be/daXEp4HmS-E?t=1785)

Comment: Interesting concept of stage barrier

Comment: you can also link to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148991/difference-between-repartition1-and-coalesce1